# Can the xmpp pubsub service(XEP-0060) create a node when it receives a subscribe request?

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe

We use XMPP XEP-0060 pub/sub feature to build a notification system.

According to XEP-0060, node can be created automatically when publishing.

My question is can it be created when **subscribing**?

If not, is there any alternative solution to implement this? (create node after subscribed)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no inherent reason this can't be done transparently on the server-side. Prosody has a service-wide autocreate_on_subscribe option, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Not via the XEP, as it doesn't specifically have that use case.  You will have to either use a server that supports this natively, (as mentioned by @MattJ) or extend one to do so yourself, as most XMPP servers have some form of plugin/extension mechanism built in.

The caveat though, is that this is no longer to spec and you will be tied to a specific implementation so your application will not be portable.